# Mapping lat/lon coordinate pairs to a given EPSG:4326 projected cartesian coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, epsg

I want to find out the timezone a GPX track is in by looking up the first coordinate pair. I took the shapefile from [Timezone Boundary Builder](https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder) and created a PNG image via qgis from it (using the default projection, "WGS 84 – EPSG:4326"), with one color per defined timezone. I also have a color-timezone mapping.

I know the width and the height of the image (which represents all possible coordinates on earth), and I have a lat/lon pair. Now I "only" need to map the coordinate pair to the respective pixel (x/y) to get it's color, which then maps to the timezone I need.

But how do I calculate the mapping? I know how to do it using the Mercator projection (I wrote a function doing that some time ago: [mercatorProjection](https://gitlab.com/l3u/gpx2svg/-/blob/d40e6887333413a7fc0e7dde8962a5cc51c5f6ab/gpx2svg#L74), but I'm struggling to find respective code for EPSG:4326 (or WGS84).

Comment: In what projection is your timezone image?

Comment: EPSG:4326 – thus I need to calculate this projection. qgis says "WGS 84 – EPSG:4326". I also added this to the text now to clarify it.

Comment: This then means you have simple linear cartesian math. Upper side of image has `y=90`, bottom has `y=-90`, left side has `x=-180`, right side has `x=180`. Conversion to image pixels is then just linear function, taking into account image size in pixels.

Comment: @TomazicM: It's really that easy?! The Mercator projection was much more complicated. Thanks for this hint :-) Is there some reference one can read about this? I really found nothing.

Comment: It's easy because EPSG:4326 is not a projection. In your case [lat, lng] values are simply used on a flat surface, without any projection calculus.

Comment: Do you want to write a few sentences as an answer I can accept? Thanks a lot for clarifying this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EPSG:4326` is not a projected coordinate system, but ellipsoidal coordinate system, using degrees for longitude and latitude coordinates. In your case these `[lng, lat]` values are simply used on a flat surface as cartesian coordinates.

This then means you have simple linear cartesian math. Upper side of image has `y=90`, bottom has `y=-90`, left side has `x=-180`, right side has `x=180`. Conversion to image pixels is then just linear function, taking into account image size in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Just to also leave the code here: This is how I map coordinates to the image (`m_timezoneMap` is a `QImage` created from the said PNG file):

```
const double width = m_timezoneMap.size().width();
const double height = m_timezoneMap.size().height();

// Scale the coordinates to the image size, relative to the image center
int mappedLon = std::round(lastCoordinates.lon() / 180.0 * (width / 2.0));
int mappedLat = std::round(lastCoordinates.lat() / 90.0 * (height / 2.0));

// Move the mapped coordinates to the left lower edge
mappedLon = width / 2 + mappedLon;
mappedLat = height - (height / 2 + mappedLat);

// Get the respective pixel's color
const auto timezoneColor = m_timezoneMap.pixelColor(mappedLon, mappedLat).name();
```